# Batch File | Parent Directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, cmd, parent

Hell all, I'm a newbie of Batch File
I have a batch File like:

```
@ECHO OFF
if not exist To_delete mkdir To_delete
if not exist resources mkdir resources
copy "C:\icon.png" "resources"

cd /d To_delete
echo The current folder is : "%CD%"
echo The icon.png is located at "CODE_I_NEED_IS_HERE"

The result should be：
The current folder is : C:\Users\Leona\Desktop\To_delete\
The icon.png is located at C:\Users\Leona\Desktop\Resource\
```

**Attention: I don't want to get the path of icon.png by CD in that folder, what i want is to retrieve the files inside resources folder when the current folder is "To_delete".**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
if not exist To_delete mkdir To_delete
if not exist resources mkdir resources
copy "C:\Documents and Settings\mlastg\Desktop\logo.png" "resources"

cd /d To_delete
echo The current folder is : "%CD%" 
dir /s/b/A:-D "%CD%\..\resources"
```

Last command will give you the path of all the files in the resources folder. now you can elaborate to get your answer

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mlastg\Desktop>batch.bat
        1 file(s) copied.
The current folder is : "C:\Documents and Settings\mlastg\Desktop\To_delete"
C:\Documents and Settings\mlastg\Desktop\resources\logo.png
```

Comment: dir /s/b/A:-D "%CD%\..\resources" is not what i want,but
%CD%\..\resources is exactly what i want.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to change to the parent diretory you can use

```
cd ..
```

so if you are in "To_delete" your command needs to look like this

```
cd ..\Resource
```

to get into the Resource folder

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as i memtioned before, i don't want to do a cd.

Comment: I just thought this would help you to change your code, so that you know how to get into resource via the parent directory ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it with a FOR loop and the file modifier `~f`.
Look also at `FOR /?`

```
for %%a in ("%CD%\..\resources") do set resourceDir=%%~fa
echo The icon.png is located at "%resourceDir%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `../` (or `..\` for Windows)?
For example: `echo The icon.png is located at "..\Resource\"`

Comment: You should add some context to your answer, alone this information is not useful, you would have a higher chance of being marked as an answer if you include at least one sample.